# 2 Loops in the same macro

Tags: vba, excel

i have been working on this code that has a loop to open each file in a column and then should do another loop that copy each line of a column. When i run the first loop it works fine, but when i added the second one it's not working. Could someone help me? Thank you very much

```
Sub teste()

Dim myRng As Range

Dim myCell As Range

Workbooks("TIME_SHEET_MACRO").Activate

With WorkSheets("Base de dados")

    Set myRng = .Range("E1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp))

    Set myRnge = .Range("B2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))

    For Each myCell In myRng.Cells

        For Each myCells In myRnge.Cells

        If .Cells(myCell.Row, "E").Value <> "" Then

            Workbooks.Open (myCell)

            Workbooks("TIME_SHEET_MACRO").Activate

            WorkSheets("Base de dados").Activate

        If .Cells(myCells.Row, "B").Value <> "" Then

            ActiveCell.Copy

        End If

    Next myCell

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Always helps to format your code and use indenting to help others read it...

Comment: You're missing `next` and `end if`

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each myCell In myRng.Cells
    For Each myCells In myRnge.Cells
        If .Cells(myCell.Row, "E").Value <> "" Then
            Workbooks.Open (myCell)
            Workbooks("TIME_SHEET_MACRO").Activate
            WorkSheets("Base de dados").Activate
        If .Cells(myCells.Row, "B").Value <> "" Then
            ActiveCell.Copy
        End If
Next myCell
```

**should be-**

```
For Each myCell In myRng.Cells
    For Each myCells In myRnge.Cells
        If .Cells(myCell.Row, "E").Value <> "" Then
            Workbooks.Open (myCell)
            Workbooks("TIME_SHEET_MACRO").Activate
            WorkSheets("Base de dados").Activate
        End If
        If .Cells(myCells.Row, "B").Value <> "" Then
            ActiveCell.Copy
        End If
    Next myCells
Next myCell
```